# Pyinstaller and cython application files way too huge

Tags: python, compression, cython, executable, pyinstaller

I am creating executables that can run on my laptop without having Python installed.  The below works perfectly...

```
pyinstaller -r file_a.so,dll,file_a.so -r file_b.so,dll,file_b.so -F ./bin/hello
```

However each executable is 181,177kb+.  When before the job was about 10kbs.  I can compress that down to 170,100kbs.

Any ideas on how I can compress this further.  It is using cython + Pyinstaller which works perfectly however the only issue is the huge size.....

[image]

Comment: This is mostly to do with the need to include the Python standard library. It looks like you can try to exclude the bits of it you don't think you use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249624/pyinstaller-very-big-file-size.

Comment: @DavidW Indeed, I used default python on my laptop and tried to install it.  It changed from a whopping 150mb file to 5mb!